# How to implement findById in two different Model using Node and MongoDB(Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two different models in my system which are the following:

StudentModel.js

```
 const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

const Student = mongoose.model("student", studentSchema);

module.exports = Student;
```

UserModel.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  passwordHashed: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

const User = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

What I want is to findById in both of these models and how can I do that? Currently, this is the code that I have but it only implements in only one of the models which is the User.

```
jwt.verify(token, "secret", async (err, decodedToken) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
      } else {
        let user = await User.findById(decodedToken.user);
        const { email, role } = user;
        res.json({ email, role });
      }
    }
```

How can I implement findById in both of the Models? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have to save StudentModel _id in User model this will be done when you create User model you have to pass studenModel _id in your req.body

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  passwordHashed: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  student: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'student',
      required: true
    }
});
const User = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

now use **populate** to get students data just like that

```
let user = await User.findById(req.params.id).populate({
    path: 'student',
    select: 'email role'
  });
```

Comment: because you don't send student object id  while creating user model